# Calling async static method from Asp.Net Web Api controller

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

I have a synchronous [HttpPost] API I'm calling from client application. During its run, when some specific conditions occur, I want it to call static method asynchronously - I don't need to wait for its result in the main method. Here's my API method:

```
public class ProcessController : ApiController
    {
        private Models.DbModel db = new Models.DbModel();

        public IHttpActionResult EditProcess(string token, int id, int UserId, JDE_Processes item, bool UseServerDates = true)
        {
            if (token != null && token.Length > 0)
            {
                var tenants = db.JDE_Tenants.Where(t => t.TenantToken == token.Trim());
                if (tenants.Any())
                {
                    var items = db.JDE_Processes.AsNoTracking().Where(u => u.TenantId == tenants.FirstOrDefault().TenantId && u.ProcessId == id);
                    if (items.Any())
                    {
                        item.CreatedOn = items.FirstOrDefault().CreatedOn;
                        if (items.FirstOrDefault().StartedOn != null)
                        {
                            //It has already had a date. Keep it
                            item.StartedOn = items.FirstOrDefault().StartedOn;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (item.StartedOn != null && UseServerDates)
                            {
                                //this has just been started. Must have been planned before. Replace user's date
                                item.StartedOn = DateTime.Now;
                                item.LastStatusBy = UserId;
                                item.LastStatusOn = DateTime.Now;

                                //if ActionType of this process requires closing all previous processes of the type, do it now
                                Utilities.CompleteAllProcessesOfTheTypeInThePlace((int)item.PlaceId, (int)item.ActionTypeId, id, UserId, "Test"); <-- HERE

                            }
                        }
                        string descr = "Edycja zgłoszenia";

                        JDE_Logs Log = new JDE_Logs { UserId = UserId, Description = descr, TenantId = tenants.FirstOrDefault().TenantId, Timestamp = DateTime.Now, OldValue = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(items.FirstOrDefault()), NewValue = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(item) };
                        db.JDE_Logs.Add(Log);
                        db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
                        try
                        {
                            db.SaveChanges();
                        }
                        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                        {
                            if (!JDE_ProcessesExists(id))
                            {
                                return NotFound();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                throw;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }
    }
```

And here's the asynchronous method I'm calling:

```
public static class Utilities
    {
        private static Models.DbModel db = new Models.DbModel();


        public async static Task CompleteAllProcessesOfTheTypeInThePlace(int thePlace, int theType, int excludeProcess, int UserId, string reasonForClosure = null)
        {

            bool? requireClosing = db.JDE_ActionTypes.Where(i => i.ActionTypeId == theType).FirstOrDefault().ClosePreviousInSamePlace;
            if(requireClosing == null) { requireClosing = false; }
            if ((bool)requireClosing)
            {
                IQueryable<JDE_Processes> processes = null;
                processes = db.JDE_Processes.Where(p => p.PlaceId == thePlace && p.ActionTypeId==theType && p.ProcessId<excludeProcess && (p.IsCompleted == false || p.IsCompleted == null) && (p.IsSuccessfull == false || p.IsSuccessfull == null));
                if (processes.Any())
                {
                    foreach(var p in processes)
                    {
                        CompleteProcessAsync(db,(int)processes.FirstOrDefault().TenantId, p, UserId, reasonForClosure);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public async static void CompleteProcessAsync(int tenantId, JDE_Processes item, int UserId, string reasonForClosure = null)
        {
            string OldValue = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(item);
            item.FinishedOn = DateTime.Now;
            item.FinishedBy = UserId;
            item.IsActive = false;
            item.IsCompleted = true;
            item.IsFrozen = false;
            item.LastStatus = (int)ProcessStatus.Finished;
            item.LastStatusBy = UserId;
            item.LastStatusOn = DateTime.Now;
            var User = db.JDE_Users.AsNoTracking().Where(u => u.UserId == UserId).FirstOrDefault();
            if (reasonForClosure == null)
            {
                item.Output = $"Przymusowe zamknięcie zgłoszenia przez {User.Name + " " + User.Surname}";
            }
            else
            {
                item.Output = reasonForClosure;
            }

            JDE_Logs Log = new JDE_Logs { UserId = UserId, Description = "Zamknięcie zgłoszenia", TenantId = tenantId, Timestamp = DateTime.Now, OldValue = OldValue, NewValue = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(item) };
            db.JDE_Logs.Add(Log);
            db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }


    }
```

There are 3 problems (or more doubts) I have with my code:

- Since Utilities.CompleteAllProcessesOfTheTypeInThePlace() is not awaited, I assume it is ran on some background thread. I mean, EditProcess() doesn't wait for it to finish, right?
- Normally I use Task.Run(()=> action()) to run something on the background thread, I don't know if that's good practice or common mistake, I've been just taught like that. In this case, however, the method won't be called at all if I try to run it from Task.Run(). Why?
- I was getting "***SqlException: New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session***" at db.SaveChanges() in CompleteProcessAsync, probably because I was using separate dbContext created in background thread. When I replaced that separate dbContext with main context passed to those methods, it started to work. Is that solution good?

Comment: Entity Framework is not thread safe.  You need to await each `SaveChanges()` or spin up multiple DbContexts.  You definitely shouldn't be sharing the same context for each request.

Comment: So if I'll be calling await CompleteProcessAsync() AND remove SaveChanges() in it so db is saved only 1 time from main method, will it be ok?

Comment: Well, just have a thought, if CompleteAllProcessesOfTheTypeInThePlace() is called asynchronously and it takes more time than main method, its results won't be saved since saving is done in the main method.. Ok, so if I can't use separate dbContext (SqlException) AND shouldn't be passing dbContext, why I can do?